# Loop pages and crawler the contents in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I would like to crawler the content from [this link](http://www.eoechina.com.cn/cn2019/gonggaoxinxi.html?classID=1):

[image]

[image]

How could I loop all the pages and crawler all the elements in the red cirle? Thanks.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'http://www.eoechina.com.cn/cn2019/gonggaoxinxi.html?classID=1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an end-point you can query to loop over the pages.

Here's how:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests
import pandas as pd

end_point = "http://www.eoechina.com.cn/cn2016/mobile/GetArticleList.ashx"

payload = {
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "classID": 1,
    "searchKey": "",
    "selectItemID": "72,"
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:86.0) "
                  "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

for page in range(1, 5):
    payload["pageNumber"] = page
    response = requests.post(
        end_point,
        data=urlencode(payload),
        headers=headers,
    ).json()
    # print("\n".join(item["title"] for item in response))
    df = pd.DataFrame(response)
    print(df)
```

Sample output: (It's a screenshot because SO thinks that the output is spam...)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how could I extract all items of `response` and append `"articleID", "title", "addTime", "qdPrice", "states"` as a dataframe?

Comment: The response is a list of dicts, so just dump that to a `pandas DataFrame`.

Comment: One more problem, how could I save the link of each item, such as http://www.eoechina.com.cn/cn2019/articleDetails1.html?articleID=22695 ?

Comment: Its xpath is `//*[@id="app"]/article/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/a`.

Comment: Use the article id from the response and build the URL yourself. For example, `http://www.eoechina.com.cn/cn2019/articleDetails1.html?articleID=THE_ARTCILE_ID_FROM_THE_RESPONSE`

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe `cn2019` in the url will change based on year?

Comment: Don't know. But try it out, experiment! See where this takes you. :)